# Google OAuth Credentials Redirect URIs problems

Tags: xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I have an app in xamarin forms, and I need to implement Google authentication. In my Google API, I have OAuth credentials using Web Application.

The problem is in the Authorized redirect URIs: when I configure the URI using the https, I can choose what account to log in to. After choosing the one I want, I get this error:

[image]

Seeing some Youtube videos, I´ve seen that I need to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, but when I try to use this way, I get this error BEFORE I get the Google user´s accounts lists:

[image]

So I´m sticking in it and can´t authenticate the user.

I´m using Xamarin Forms, and on the app, there´s no exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI (where the response is returned to) has to be registered in the APIs console, and the error is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your `client ID` & `client secret` there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Note that updating the google api console and that change being present can take some time. Generally only a few minutes but sometimes it seems longer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @leo Zhu, but the problem was in my ASP.NET CORE API. I need to change my DefaultAuthenticateScheme to CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme instead of JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.

Comment: @JuniorThurler Do you set the Redirect URIs to your domain? When you auth successfully, you should re-back to the Activity by `IntentFilter`